# How to pass grid data to another page?

Tags: php, grid

I am new to PHP. I have a page containing a grid. Users can edit some values in the grid. When they click a submit button, I would like to pass all of the grid data to the action page. However, I don't know how to do this. Please give your inputs.

Comment: Please add your code in Question which you use or try.

Comment: Hey newbie...when you ask a question be specific and clear what you are asking..So try to include your code in the question..

Comment: which grid are you using??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For eg. if your form is like this, you can give the name for text like as below.

```
<form name="form_submit" method="post" action="">           
   <table>
      <tr>
         <td><input type="text" name="title[]" /></td>
         <td><input type="text" name="text[]" /></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td><input type="text" name="title[]" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="text[]" /></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td><input type="text" name="title[]" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="text[]" /></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td><input type="text" name="title[]" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="text[]" /></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" /></td>
       </tr>
   </table>
</form>
```

When you submit, the output of the values will be in the form of an array like below.

```
Array
(
    [title] => Array
        (
            [0] => test
            [1] => test1
            [2] => test2
            [3] => test3
        )

    [text] => Array
        (
            [0] => test
            [1] => test1
            [2] => test2
            [3] => test3
        )

    [submit] => Submit
)
```

Comment: Great Saranya sadhasivam. It did not strike my mind to use array like name="title[]. i was thinking with name="title" instead of name="title[]. once again thanks a lot. I will be asking you many more questions in future.

Answer (score 0):

Data persistence can be handled in one of two ways.

Option 1: Save the data to a file

Option 2: Save the data to a database

I almost always opt for Option 2 as usually there is more than one set of data you want to persist.

In your use case you would have a PHP script as the action url in the form.
The PHP script would then validate and persist the data.

A separate page (or script) could then access this data via the means selected.

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="action.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="username">
<input type="password" name="password">
<button type="submit">save</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

action.php

```
<?php
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];

echo $username."\r\n";
echo $password."\r\n";
?>
```

I suggest you before learn php you should learn html.